How to manually set a window's title in GNU screen while using dynamic window titles?
I have set up dynamic window titles as described in screen's documentation with shelltitle '$ |bash' in my .screenrc because my prompt ends with '$ ' and I want the default title to be "bash".
However, sometimes I want to give an explicit name to a window to describe its purpose. Usually, after I've already created it.
When I use the title command (either ctrl-a A or ctrl-a :title) to set the name, it gets overwritten the next time I hit enter at the prompt.
How can I stop the new title from being overwritten?
But also, I don't just want a static new title. I want the new title to be $ |new-name:, which the documentation says will make the title be new-name:<cmd>.
So I wouldn't want all dynamic titling to stop for this window. I want a new dynamic title.
How can I set that?

i tried it for some time and it turned out the effect of '$ |bash' or '$ |bash:' cannot be reverted. looks like a bug to me.
